# Открытие страниц приложения в окнах

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, меня давно уже интересует решение одной идеи которая возникла у меня в голове, может кто подскажет правильное решение, итак суть:

Хочется сделать сайт по типу десктоп приложения, компоненты, рюшечки, это все дело пятое, вся загвостка у меня с тем что каждый раздел меню должен открываться в окнах, т.е. каждая из страниц сайта открывается в окне, оно может быть модальным и не модальным, в зависимости от раздела, так вот, когда окно не модальное, следовательно его можно открыть несколько раз, тобишь если я подгружу его через ajax в первый раз будет все ОК, но если я открою повторно это окно все бинды к кнопкам и прочие функции отработают не правильно т.к. в DOM уже есть первое такое окно, с такими id, как решается данная проблема? У меня пока было два варианта это

1. Подгружать содержимое окна в iframe(но как то не камильфо)
2. Давать контейнеру окна уникальный идентификатор и искать объкты для бинда именно в этом контейнере типо того:

> `<div id="modal_container_8838921"></div>`

Но мне кажется люди решают это по другому..

---

Представьте обычное десктоп приложение допустим телефонный справочник, в нем есть раздел "абоненты" при нажатии на этот раздел у вас открывается новое окно со списком абонентов и предоставляется возможность редактирования данного справочника, если вы нажмете еще раз на раздел "абоненты" у вас откроется еще одно такое же окно, первое не закрывается, вы можете работать со справочником как в первом окне так и во втором, тоже самое я хочу реализовать сайтом, проблема лишь в том что если я буду вязать функции on('click') и т.д. за класс или id объекта в DOM это работать не будет, вернее будет, но только для первого открытого окна.

---

Да, конечно можно было бы просто ставить фокус на первое окно, а не открывать второе, но такую "хотелку" хочет мой начальник, для того что бы пользователи могли сверять данные, так удобней. А вариант того что можно открыть второе окно в браузере не хочет.

Comment: Не уверен, что понял что именно Вы хотите и в чем проблема. Но нельзя ли просто стереть это окно из DOM после того как один раз использовали его?

Comment: просто не используй id, вместо него используй классы

Comment: А за чем мне, как пользователю, два одинаковых окна? почему нельзя делать так: если это окно уже открыто - делаем просто на него фокус, если не открыто - открываем.

Comment: Еще хочу сказать, что при такой реализации, вам придется одновременно осуществлять изменения в обоих одинаковых окнах, а это не всегда может оказаться тривиальной задачей.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь формой для объединения учетных записей: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact (выберите *Мне необходимо объединить учётные записи*).

Answer (score 1):

Подписываешься живой подпиской, в обработчике поднимаешься до селектора окна и все элементы ищешь в нём:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-btn', function (event) {
  var $component = $(event.target).closest('.window-class');

  var $smth = $component.find('.smth');
  ...
});
```